# Integrate google ads in google sheets using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

Really sorry if this is the basic question.

I have been searching for two days to find the documentation/sample function to use in apps script that fetches google ads accounts, reports, etc. what I have found all, is the documentation for languages like PHP, python, c, etc and they are giving me tough time understanding them. I know integrating google ads in google sheets is possible as google itself has published an add-on to fetch the reports but can't find any hint either in this platform or in the official documentation. any help will be highly appreciated.

Note: I am seeking help for integrating google ads in google sheets through **apps script** not **ads script**. I know there are functions available for ads script even in the documentation but none I found for apps script to the best of my research.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's no Google Ads-specific functionality in AppsScript. The list of supported "Other Google services" in the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) only lists Adsense, Campaign Manager and Google Shopping as accessible products in the "Google Ads and Merchant Center" section.

If you want to upload Ads data into a Google Spreadsheet, you can still use Ads Script's [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/spreadsheetapp).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. of course, there is nothing related to google ads in advance services of apps script but as Google has even published a GS add-on that fetches ads reports to google sheet so there must be a way of integrating. The 2nd link you have provided shows **Service Unavailable** on my side.

Comment: I suppose you can use the [URL Fetch Service of AppsScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) and call the Google Ads API's [rest interface](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/overview) from there. Just be aware that it's going to be quite some effort to implement compared to just using [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/spreadsheetapp).

Comment: Both of these links say **Service Unavailable** on my side.

1. *https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/overview*

2. *https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/spreadsheetapp*

Comment: They work for me. Not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: don't know there is something going on in my browser. The URLs are not opening in the browser logged in with my account but when opened in incognito mode, they worked fine. BY the I have read all the documentation and followed each and every step. The 2nd URL for the spreadsheet only showed the methods to be used in the ads script for exporting data so couldn't get much help from them. the 1st URL that you provided, still couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: like it tells of authorization stuff which I have already done in the sheet for some other google integration. the below-provided snippets only inform about authorization not about getting the data from ads. what I need is, a method of getting data from google ads to google sheets through apps script.

Comment: OK, I hope you succeed.